# how to clipRect a textview?

Tags: android, textview, clipping

I could clipRect(hide/show using the rectangle--canvas.clipRect) anything drawn by the onDraw method of a textView. Now is it possible to clipRect the textView drawn by the TextView class by default?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to override onDraw() to perform your own custom drawing operations. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: i am trying to slowly reveal my textview from left to right. so lets say i have textview with text = "Hello World". It would initially hide all the text, then slowly shows H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d.  I tried over writing the textview's onDraw but it still couldn't clipRect to my textview's text, instead, it would only clipRect the text that is drawn by canvas.drawText. Any idea how to clipRect on the textview's text?